# Range Error : Maximum call stack size increases

Tags: angular5

ERROR in : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at checkDiagnostics (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/gather_diagnostics.js:32:28)
    at Object.gatherDiagnostics (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/gather_diagnostics.js:42:13)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:706:65)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:577:54)
    at

0% compiling/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/gather_diagnostics.js:32
            allDiagnostics.push(...diags);
                           ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at checkDiagnostics (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/gather_diagnostics.js:32:28)
    at Object.gatherDiagnostics (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/gather_diagnostics.js:42:13)
    at TypeChecker._diagnose (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/type_checker.js:118:53)
    at TypeChecker.update (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/type_checker.js:140:14)
    at process.on (/home/agami/Whatup cuz/WhatupCUZ_updated/WhatUpCuz/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/type_checker.js:64:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:774:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: looking at error it seems a function is calling itself recursively. if you share some code we can be more helpful